# How to Install Kubuntu over Lubuntu?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, lubuntu, kubuntu, windows-8

I have a Windows 8 computer set to dual-boot with Lubuntu. I want to make the computer dual-boot Kubuntu instead of Lubuntu. How can I install Kubuntu over Lubuntu? I don't want to loose Windows 8. Both Lubuntu and Kubuntu are version 13.04.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be the same like re-installing any operating system. You have to simply boot Kubuntu using live CD/DVD/USB and install at the partition where Lubuntu is installed..

Comment: I am not familiar with the Kubuntu disk partitioning tool. Could you provide instructions/pictures? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is simply to install the KDE desktop on the existing Lubuntu. It comes in a package named *kubuntu-desktop*, search for it in the Software Centre. After it is installed you can then choose to login either with the Kubuntu DE or the Lubuntu DE (isn't that great?).

P.S.: you can follow [this guide](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/kde) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from t he Kubuntu CD/DVD, and follow the images below.  I've tested this with 12.04, but it should be the same for 13.04.

[image]
[image]
[image]